# Why is exponent(0.0) a DomainError?

Tags: floating-point, julia

Why does `exponent(0.0)` give a domain error? It seems like the exponent of `0.0` should be the same as the exponent of `1.0` which is 0. Since zero is an Int, I am confused why that would be out of the domain (or is it a bug? But since an error is set here, it seems to be a conscious choice).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lets play with the values to see:

```
julia> exponent(2.0)                                                                                                                                       
1 --- 2^1 = 2

julia> exponent(4.0)                                                                                                                                       
2 --- 2^2 = 4

julia> exponent(1.0)                                                                                                                                       
0 --- 2^0 = 1

julia> exponent(0.5)                                                                                                                                       
-1 --- 2^-1 = 0.5

julia> exponent(0.25)                                                                                                                                       
-2 --- 2^-2 = 0.25

.
.
.
```

So that means:

```
julia> exponent(0.0)                                                                                                                                       
-∞ --- 2^-∞ = 0.0
```

Negative infinity is causing the domain error.

Comment: Oh duh... my brain wasn't working for a bit. Good explanation.

Comment: But since `2.0^(-1024) == 0.0` without error, by same spirit of silent overflows, it is plausible to have `expoenent(0.0) == -1024` without error. Especially considering this is faithful to actual exponent bit representation in Float64 (by the IEEE754 standard). Just saying it's plausible. Current behavior is closer to mathematical truth.

Comment: But using `exponent(0.0) == -1024` is inconsistent with the fact that `exponent(nextfloat(0.0)) == -1074`.

Comment: The debatable (not here/now) vibe of silent overflows tries to prioritize speed of un-heavily scrutinized code. The `exponent(0.0)==-1024` should be faster to implement in a hot loop (one would want to avoid subnormal floats, as `nextfloat(0.0)` in calculations). To prioritize correctness `2.0^(-1024)` should return Domain Error (BTW I'm good with the current priorities, but methods should allow easy choice to depart into more correctness and exceptions).

Comment: To concretize `fast_exponent(x::Float64) = Int(reinterpret(UInt64,x)&Base.exponent_mask(Float64)>>52) - 1023`, is faster and in-lined and is valid for good Float64s (fails silently otherwise). Perhaps some reader is interested.